# threejs rotation by radians in a plane

Tags: three.js, rotation

If I have an angle in radians, `theta`, how do I set the rotation of an object (Object3D) to `theta`, with respect to the x-z plane? I am surprisingly unable to find any examples for this use case.

Comment: object.rotation.y = theta ?

Comment: aha, that has got me somewhere, thanks :) I should be able to work it out from here

Comment: Cool! I help moderate a threejs slack group if you want to give or get live feedback/assistance. :) https://join.slack.com/t/threejs/shared_invite/enQtMzYxMzczODM2OTgxLTQ1YmY4YTQxOTFjNDAzYmQ4NjU2YzRhNzliY2RiNDEyYjU2MjhhODgyYWQ5Y2MyZTU3MWNkOGVmOGRhOTQzYTk

Hit me up.. I'm thrax on there.

Comment: rotating the object in object space: object.rotateOnAxis ( object.up, theta ); (the up vector is a vector3(0, 1, 0) aka. the y axis of the object.)